# Suffixes -ly vs -age

Tags: difference

In general, what are the similarities and differences?

For example, what about [assembly](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assembly) vs [assemblage](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/assemblage)?

> The rural
>   proletariat moved to the urban centers and helped reproduce new forms of rural
>   spaces. The arcade is overturning this **assemblage** of aesthetics and ethics and
>   makes consumption a spatial practice distinguished from that of the spaces of
>   production.

Source: p 146, *Mastering the National Admissions Test for Law*, Mark Shepherd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are very few words which could correctly end with both -ly and -age, so "assemblage" and "assembly" are better thought of as two separate words, not one word stem with two suffixes.

*Assemblage* usually just implies a diverse collection that doesn't necessarily have any order to it, as in "the dragon's hoard was a vast assemblage of golden treasures".

*Assembly*, by contrast, usually implies some kind of structure, order, or relationship between the individual pieces, as in "an assembly of union workers striking for higher pay at the factory".